# how to keep values in textbox even after refreshing the same page in html?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have month-picker in a form (i.e customized date picker to pick just months and year) which I submit by using simple submit button in html. But after submission of the form the value (month and year) disappears from the textbox. I want to retain the value even after the page refresh (on submission). I need simplest way to do it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide some of your html and php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the value in COOKIE

Use button Instead submit, something like this:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    return null;
}


    $("document").ready(function(){
      document.getElementById('dateTextBoxValue').value=readCookie("dateValue");
      $(".submit").click(function(event){
         var dateValueText=document.getElementById('dateTextBoxValue').value;
         document.cookie = "dateValue="+dateValueText;
      });

    });
```

Comment: thanks! It worked with slight modifications as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You've not talked about what browsers you want to support, but if you are only interested in modern browsers, I would recommend [HTML5's LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Comment: LocalStorage I have tried it. But not sure if I'm trying in right direction. Thanks for the link. Also Support is expected for Chrome recent stable version.

Comment: LocalStorage works fine in Chrome, FireFox and IE8 and above. You can check compatibility at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstora)